# How to handle likes and dislikes in application with API

Tags: mongodb, api, next.js, database-design, prisma

I have a Nextjs application with Prisma and Mongodb. Users can like/dislike posts on their feeds.
It works pretty well, but the problem is when the post is liked by the user, then he dislikes and likes again really fast. It causes a problem with the database because the second request may process before the database was updated by the first one, so it incorrectly updates the like/dislike count.

The current logic:
I have a User document, that has a field called reactions. This field is a JSON with objects that have key value pairs, key=id of the post and value=like/dislike. Ex: d9287hd78absyudabs: 'like'.
In the Post document, I have a field called likes and one called dislikes, so I add or subtract according to the API calls.

I already implemented solutions for the client side, but somebody could simply call the API route as if it was using the client buttons.
How could I implement a robust solution for that?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry, but in its current state, your question might get downvoted or closed. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking so people can help you better.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @YoussoufOumar I understand, but my question is about software architecture, not the code necessarily. This is a problem called 'race condition', pretty common in software engineering. The solution is in the logic, not the code. But thank you for helping me!

Comment: The thing is that your question is more architectural and not specific to an obstacle you are facing. They could close it for not being [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Maybe you would wanna check other [Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for non-scoped opened and architectural questions, like [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).